# How does the computer know what port is a packet for?

Tags: sockets

Let's assume I'm in computer A, I have a few servers running on different ports, but all are basically an instance of the same program (just binding to different ports). Now, computer B, a client, does he need to know what port is the software he wishes to connect to on computer A?

The point is, I am implementing some sort of communication similar to sockets. Everything should work fine but I'm not sure how to create the initial-message from a computer to another - I just don't know to what port to send it to. Does the client know the port he's sending to on the server?

Say here (client): `clientsocket.connect(('localhost', 8089))`, does the client connect a server running on port 8089? If so, what port is his socket on (what port is he using for the client?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The only way for the network stack on computer A to know which process to deliver an incoming packet is for computer B to set the correct port in the packet. A web server runs on port 80 by default, but a machine running several distinct web servers will run them on distinct ports, and a client must be specific about which server they want to connect to. `http://example.com`, `http://example.com:8080`, and `http://example.com:12345` would refer to the servers running on `example.com` on ports 80, 8080, and 12345, respectively.

In order to know which port to use in your client, you need to read the documentation for the server you want to connect to.

Going in the other direction, the port used by the client to receive responses is typically set by the networking stack automatically. The client doesn't need to do anything special to set it, and the server simply sends packets back to the address/port found in the source portion of the incoming packet.

Comment: Thanks, but on what computer will the socket be on computer B? Say, I sniff the packets and I see that the destination port is 80 (I'm contacting a web server), but what line of code, if any, determines the source port.

Comment: If you have the packet (and I'm assuming it's a TCP socket), it's source port field of the packet header, which is the 2-byte field preceding the destination port.